# CometD and Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, cometd

I am trying to implement a CometD application with kafka.

Use Case: I establish a cometD connection when sending a message it publishes to Kafka Producer so far good. I have a Servlet listener to intialize a kafka consumer and poll the messages from a topic. I am using the ServerSession to deliver message the message back to client. When multiple consumers from the same group poll the messages it might poll the response meant for another consumer which contains the unique id to which the message has to be delivered but it could find it since the session id is present on another host on which another consumer is running. Could anyone help me understand how i can handle this situation

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you have to re-phrase the question to make it more clear. Use names such as `serverA`, `serverB`, etc. to indicate the CometD server, the Kafka producer, the Kafka consumers, the hosts, etc. because right now it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: ServerA Running ConsumerA and ServerB running ConsumerB. ServerA initiate a comet session say ServerSessionA. Both ConsumerA and ConsumerB are polling from a ToipcA. Now the response meant for ConsumerA is polled by ConsumerB since they have the group.id say GroupA, but the ServerSession does not exist on ConsumerB. I want to deliver the message to ServerSessionA over the channel how do i achieve this.

Comment: If you want the messages to be consumed by ConsumeA, why do you setup ConsumerB at all? Remove ConsumerB and everything will work.